# How to add post 'category' option to custom Wordpress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Im following a tutorial to create a custom Wordpress them from scratch, but I'm creating my site slightly different. The tutorial created a project page, but I'm making a blog page and I need to add the ability to select categories for the posts.

I couldn't find the information on wordpress.org. Here is my code from the functions.php file. What do I need to add to this code so that I'll have the option to add categories?

```
function gt_custom_post_type() {
  register_post_type('investing', 
    array(
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'investing posts'),
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Investing Posts',
        'singular_name' => 'Investing Post',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Investing Post',
        'edt_item' => 'Edit Investing Post',
      ),
      'menu-icon' => 'dashicons-clipboard',
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'supports' => array(
        'title', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'comments'
      )
    )
  );
}

add_action('init', 'gt_custom_post_type');
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the anwer

```
'taxonomies'  => array( 'category' )
```

here

[How to Add Categories to a Custom Post Type in WordPress](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-categories-to-a-custom-post-type-in-wordpress/)